# Convexity of the scalar product in the Alexandrov space

Tags: alexandrov-geometry

Given a point $p$ in an Alexandrov space $A$ with curvature bounded below, we denote by $T_p$ the tangent cone at $p$. For two tangent vectors $u$ and $v$ in $T_p$, we define a scalar product as follows
$$
\langle u, v \rangle:=|u||v| \cos \angle(u,v)
$$
where $\angle(u,v)$ is the angle between $u$ and $v$.

Can we show that for any $u \in T_p$, the function $x \mapsto \langle x, u \rangle$ on $T_p$ is convex?

Comment: What does the angle between two vectors in a vector space of dimension greater than 2 mean?

Comment: I suppose that dimension is finite (otherwise the tangent space might have nonintrinsic metric and convexity does not have much sense). In this case the function $x\mapsto -\langle u,x\rangle$ for unit vector $u$ is Busemann function for the half-line in the diection of $u$. So it is concave.